# The topology induced by a neighbourhood system

Tags: general-topology

My topology instructor gave the following exercise:

> Let $X \neq\varnothing$ and let $\{ N_x : x \in X \}$ be a neighbourhood system on $X$. If $\tau$ is the family of all those sets $O$ such that $O$ is a neighbourhood of each of its elements (i.e., $O \in N_x$ for each $x \in O$), then $\tau $ is the topology induced by this neighbourhood system.

I can't get how to write the union part while proving it is a topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a family $(U_i)_{i\in I}$ of open sets, i.e. each $U_i$ is a neighbourhood of its points, and set $U=\displaystyle\bigcup_{i\in I}U_i$.

If $x$ is an element of $U$, then $x$ lies in some $U_i$, which is a neighbourhood of $x$ by hypothesis. As a superset of a neighbourhood is again a neighbourhood, we know $U$ is a  neighbourhood of $x$. As this is true for any $x\in U$, we've proved $U$ is an open set.

Comment: thanks for the answer . just one doubt , that how will we prove that $X \in \tau$

Comment: $X$ is a superset of any subset, by definition…

Comment: alright ,thanks..